# Adding ripple effect to stacked views in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, rippledrawable

[image: Ripple effect problem]

I am trying to implement ripple effect to the "Vegetarian" and "Non Vegetarian" button but it is being blocked by the TextView used for button labels in both cases. Below is my XML file

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    tools:context="com.techpappy.whattoeat.MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/cherryRed">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="What would you prefer ?"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="@color/cherryRed"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:textColor="@color/wineBrown"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/vegButton"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/button_red"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="Vegetarian"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#6B2737"
                android:fontFamily="monospace"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/nonvegbutton"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/button_red"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Non Vegetarian"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#6B2737"
                android:fontFamily="monospace"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Instead a FrameLayout you can use directy a Button. You can set up background and text in the same component, in this case the Button.

Comment: That was the first thing I did but I was not able to add the material design effects to it (elevation, ripple,etc). They worked only when I used ImageButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the problem wasn't with the `TextView` but with the `ImageButton`. I removed the ImageButtons and used `Button` (keeping TextViews as it is). I used `android:backgruond = "?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"` to apply the ripple effect to the buttons and to give them my desired color I used the `android:tint` attribute.